# Lossless compressing software that grants best compression ratio for everyday purpose and/or for specific tasks

Tags: pdf, images, file-compression, zip

Hello there everybody.

My question should be rather simple for "insiders" (or I hope so at least), so here is the matter: as far as I know and understand, 7zip is currently the best lossless compression software for everyday purposes as it -generally speaking- grants the best possible compression ratio nowadays... or is it?

Ok now, assuming my premise is correct, my most specific question is this: does 7-zip always grants the best lossless compressing ratio or in specific circumstances (i.e. compressing images rather than office documents, etc.) there are "better aimed solutions"?

To be more precise, I'm interested in compressing what I have to send by email the more often, that is:

- PDF documents
- images (90% of which JPEGs)
- although rarely, binaries (executables, etc.)

Do you know any software that grants better compression ratio than 7-zip for those specific cases?

I'd greatly appreciate advices based upon statistical or technical information (i.e. compression ratio comparison, etc.). Thank you in advance.

P.S. I know that JPG is already a compressed format so it is difficult to get it to shrink more and, moreover, often PDF documents are indeed JPEGs... Clearly, I'm not so wishful of having to use many software if it is not worth the effort and, in that case, I'll go on using only 7-zip for everything.

Comment: well you are asking for a tool with better compression ration than 7zip isn't it?

Comment: In my experience, 7-zip has been better than other compression software. It also gives you a choice between different compression algorithms, so you can test different ones for different data types. If your data is too large for emails, consider either splitting the archive (7-zip supports that as well), or using an SFTP service (like Bitvise or TeamViewer) to transfer your files

Comment: 7zip isn't the best compressor, but it is the best balance compressor.  Is time a corcern for you?  Do you want another program that saves spaces, but takes an hour(depending on size of input) or more to do its job?

Comment: @cybernard : yeah, of curse time do matter... but... what d'ya have in store? ;-) If the final result really make a BIG difference on compressed size then maybe I could decide to wait for it... otherwise, as I said, if it's not worth the effort I'll stay with 7-zip.

Comment: FreeArc and PeaZip.  WinRAR is also good.  Note:  For user sanity most compression programs are only set to level 2-4.  If you adjust the settings to 9 (usually the MAX), you will achieve better compression.  There is another program, I forgot the name, but after 16 hours it still had 1-2 days left on a 40gb hard drive image. I was forced to abort.

Comment: Although I don't remember them all, I have used dozens of compression  programs.  There is 1 thing most programs forget about completely, bad sectors in your data.  I have made backup sets, put them aside, only to find the media had gotten bad sectors over time.  Some programs just completely fail to decompress these files, some just skip over the bad files, and a rare few, like WinRAR, actually have a parity option (which slightly increases file size) that can self correct a certain number of bad sectors. Sometimes, I could easily get a replacement file and others out of luck.

Comment: I know this is a non-compression idea, but here it is anyway.  If everyone uses gmail, you can share the file via google drive, and the other person will have instant access and no need to fool around with email and compression becomes optional.  You get, at least 5 if not 15gb free.  No more, oh, but we have 5 users with 10mb limits now what?  I am so done with stupid limits like that.

Comment: If you set them to Max or level 9, nanozip,uharc,FreeArc all are slooow.